# Нужна помощь с vk-ботом

Tags: vkontakte-api, python-3.7

Извиняюсь если вопрос очень глупый, только начал изучать python и vkapi. написал для поиска людей вот такой код:

```
import vk_api
import vk

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token='')
session_api = vk.get_api()


AGE_FROM = 16
AGE_TO = 50
CITY = 10

users = session_api.users.search(city=CITY, age_from=AGE_FROM, age_to=AGE_TO, fields='domain')
print(users)
```

Хочу сделать так, чтобы id пользователей которые выдаются записывались в какой-нибудь массив, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было взять id из этого массива и допустим отправлять сбщ людям из этого массива. Надеюсь корректно выложил свою мысль

Пытался как-то так:

```
IDS=[session_api.users.get(users(id))]
USER_IDS = (IDS)
print(USER_IDS)
```

сделать это, чтобы хотя бы получить просто их id, но понимаю что очень это все плохо. За помощь начинающему питонисту буду очень благодарен

Comment: была попытка еще так написать `IDS=[users.get(id)]
USER_IDS = (IDS)
print(USER_IDS)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно было обработать результат, приведу пример.

Метод [users.search](https://vk.com/dev/users.search) вернет словарь вида `{'count': <общее количествол>, 'items': [{<user_1>, {<user_2>, ...}` ваша минимальная задача из словаря вытащить `id` пользователей:

```
import vk_api

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token='')
api = vk.get_api()

AGE_FROM = 16
AGE_TO = 50
CITY = 10

rs = api.users.search(city=CITY, age_from=AGE_FROM, age_to=AGE_TO, fields='domain')
# {'count': 1151606, 'items': [{'id': 140182251, 'first_name': ...

users_ids = [user['id'] for user in rs['items']]
print(users_ids)
# [140182251, 375153774, 182159307, 13017918, 11792890, 84950588, 3691205, ...
```

---

**PS.**

Если вам нужно получить больше элементов (vk первоначально ограничивает параметром `count` из количество), то понадобится вооружиться циклом и перебрать записи через запросы.

Это будет выглядеть так:

```
...

offset = 0
count = 1000
users_ids = []

while True:
    rs = api.users.search(
        city=CITY, age_from=AGE_FROM, age_to=AGE_TO, fields='domain', offset=offset, count=count
    )
    print(rs)

    # Если хоть один из параметров пустой
    if not rs['count'] or not rs['items']:
        break

    users_ids += [user['id'] for user in rs['items']]

    offset += count

print(len(users_ids))
```

Но, к счастью, у `vk_api` есть отличная утилита для этой работы [VkTools](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html). С нею не нужно писать цикл, достаточно указать метод, его параметры и количество значений за раз:

```
from vk_api import VkTools
rs = VkTools(api).get_all(
    method='users.search',
    max_count=1000,
    values={
        'city': CITY,
        'age_from': AGE_FROM,
        'age_to': AGE_TO,
        'fields': 'domain',
    },
)
print(len(rs['items']))
```

[Официальный пример](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/a9e425cafa552cc8d528987c5adf5e8d106a304b/examples/get_full_wall.py#L17) для получения записей из стены с VkTools (этот код будет работать для запросов, у которых есть параметры `count` и `offset`, что подходит и для пользователей, и для записей со стены, и т.п.)

**PPS**

Похоже, vk не отдаст больше 1000 пользователей, поэтому если вам нужно получить больше, придется менять фильтр к запросу, чтобы было как можно больше вариантивности пользователей в ответе

Comment: Огромное спасибо, я уверен это очень поможет мне для дальнейшего понимания python и vkapi так же

Comment: @JDie, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)